# How to export sql a table structure and data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, backup

phpMyAdmin has a feature called **export**.
It will export table structure 
and its data. The output will be something like this:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `input`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `input` (
  `input_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `input_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`input_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `input`
--

INSERT INTO `input` (`input_id`, `input_type`) VALUES(1, 'text');
INSERT INTO `input` (`input_id`, `input_type`) VALUES(3, 'textarea');
INSERT INTO `input` (`input_id`, `input_type`) VALUES(5, 'radio');
INSERT INTO `input` (`input_id`, `input_type`) VALUES(6, 'checkbox');
INSERT INTO `input` (`input_id`, `input_type`) VALUES(7, 'number');
```

From my past questions on this site, I learned I can export the structure of my table
with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE  `input`;
```

Is there any way to **export data** just like in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    "INSERT INTO `input` (`input_id`, `input_type`) VALUES(",
    input_id,
    ", '",
    input_type,
    "');"
)
AS data
FROM input
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use mysqldump to generate insert commands only (for all entries in the table) without DB and Table create commands.

```
mysqldump --no-create-db --no-create-info
```

For other options, [please look here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, ther is no SQL statement that will allow you to generate INSERTS like that.

Though, if you are looking for a lazy automated processing, I guess you could dump your data with [SELECT INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html), then reload it later with [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html).